# Integration of a function which is numerical solution of differential equation

Tags: integration, ode, numerical

I've obtained a numerical solution of a differential equation in a form of a vector (i.e. M(170,1)) by using ode45, and tspan=0:500 (time range). How can I now integrate M(t)dt, when I am not sure how time sequences are distributed? I know, that I could put tspan=0:0.01:500, but I would like to save some time now.

Comment: Would this be better asked on math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

Add the integral to the differential system. If `dM/dt=F(t,M)` then the integral satisfies the differential equation `dI/dt=M`, that is `d[M,I]/dt=[F(t,M), M]`.

This also gives for `I` a numerical integration of the same error order as for `M`.